# How to get a PropertyChanged event for a child property in a ListView

Tags: xaml, .net-core, mvvm, winui-3

I have a Master/Detail View for a User Management of my App. The Master should be representeb by a List View

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.UsersView, Mode=OneWay}"
                  Width="Auto"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:User">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind UserID, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                       Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{x:Bind UserGroup.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

The problem is how to recieve updates for `UserGroup.Name`. I could use a readonly ComboBox, but as far as I know I would have to extend my `User` class with a collection of `UserGroup`which not really would make sense. Are there any further alternatives?

Best regards
Holger

Comment: The object returned by the `UserGroup` property should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for `Name` whenever it's set to a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding a method for retrieving the UserGroup name in user class and the UserGoupID as Parameter for that method (even if nor really needed). But by this UserGroup name is updated by using this method in XAML